Ubuntu won't boot on high CPU freqs
I've recently built my new PC. I was trying to install Ubntu 23.10 but installer was always producing random errors on the middle of instalation. After investigation, I managed to install Ubuntu but I had to go to BIOS and manually set CPU multiplier to lower number.
My build:

Intel Core I9-14900K
Asus ROG MAXIMUS Z790 HERO
64GB (4x16Gb) Corsair Dominator Platinum RGB DDR5 6200MHz
SABRENT 2TB Rocket Nvme PCIe 4.0 M.2

So currently I'm able to use Ubuntu but only with low cpu multipliers (50 for P-cores, 30 - for E-cores). But increaing, for example P-core multiplier to 55 leads to huge ammount of random errors, SEGFAULTs and so on. When I leave multiplier on Auto/Ai-Overclocked or set it for example to 60(for P-cores) I can't even boot into system - just black screen.
I was thinking it can be memory issue as well but decreasing ddr freq. or event removing 2 sticks didn't help.
CPU has pretty good cooling - 2x 360mm radiators (custom water loop) so I doubt it is a thermal issue (temperature rarely reaches 80+ degrees on heavy parellel tasks). Also it manages to stay stable at 6.2 Ghz in Windows.
Just curious, if anyone had such issues, maybe Im missing some BIOS settings.

Intel has recently approach this instability situation with some 13/14 gen CPUs. Take a look at:

June 2024 Guidance regarding Intel Core 13th and 14th Gen K/KF/KS instability reports

There isn't an official solution yet. In the mean time, to prevent degrading your CPU, I recommend following the Intel Default Settings recommendations in your BIOS:

